# Stopping jquery animate. Building a Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, carousel

Im learning javascript and jquery and im trying to create my own carousel. 
The current problem i have stumbled over is the following. When the user stop scrolling in the carousel, i have a function that runs and centers my targeted Carousel item to my desired point. I have illustrated this with a black line in my fiddle. Here is my function that centers that item:

```
    jQuery.fn.CenterToPoint = function(){
    return this.each(function(){

        Offset = $(this).offset().left;
        Width = $(this).width();
        Illuminate_Point = 0.45 * $(window).width();
        ScrollLeft = Illuminate_Point - (Offset+Width/2); 

        $Container.animate({scrollLeft: "-=" + ScrollLeft},450);
        }); 
}
```

However, i want the user to be able to scroll even though the animation is running. How can i kill this animation when its running but the user either clicks, mousescroll or trackpad is used on my carousel? 
Here is my jFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ptp05jvo/

Comment: not sure what you mean. It looks to be working. Nice idea by the way, looks very good

Comment: So while the animation is running, if you try and scroll it becomes choppy. Theres a conflict between the scroll of the user and my animation. I would love to learn how to have control over such an animate functions so i can cancel it when the user starts scrolling.

And thank you by the way!

Comment: If you call `$Container.stop()`, it will stop any running animation on that object. However, simply adding this into you `scroll` handler is causing issues. I think it is starting the animation, moving a tiny bit, then the scroll handler is called and stops it, then it starts again... etc. But I'm not sure about all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your problem are:

1. The box is twitching after the it reach to desired point (black line).
2. When animating (box moving towards the black line), user input will cause box to 'jump'. In this case, you would want user input to override animating scrolling.

I didn't solve the whole problem, but here's what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ptp05jvo/3/

I managed to stop the first problem (twitching) by adding the following option in `.animate()`.

```
always: function() {
    clearTimeout($Container.data('scrollTimeout'));
    isSystemScroll = false;
}
```

When you animate with `.animate()` to scroll, jQuery scroll the element and it's considered as actually scrolling, so `.scroll()` event is triggered. This can be good / bad.
In your carousel case, it's sort of bad because you `.CenterToPoint()` is called within `.scroll()` event which means it will be called every time jQuery animate the box to center.
This is what causing the twitching problem. The `.CenterToPoint()` keeps getting called within `.scroll()' event. So, the option I added will stop this.

To separate the concern, I added new jQuery function, `scrollStopped` to handle scrolling stopped event.

There is also a new variable called `isSystemScroll` that I introduced to the code. The idea is to recognize whether the scroll is coming from user / animation. With this, we can prioritize user input to override animation scroll.
However, user input can be anything, keyboard arrow, mouse wheel scroll, mouse click on scroll bar, etc. In my example, I only handle keyboard arrow input which is shown in the following code:

```
$(document).keyup(function () {
    isSystemScroll = false;
    console.log("key up");
});
```

Obviously, you can add additional check to only capture left / right arrow keys instead of all keys.

This sort of solve the 2nd problem. But you still need to handle other user inputs, esp mouse moving scroll bar.

From the test, I found that Firefox render the animation better and smoother. In Firefox, user input with keyboard arrow will override animation perfectly. The transition is smooth between the two. However, in Chrome, there's a little bit lag / jump.
Also, in Chrome, horizontal scroll bar doesn't show up while in Firefox, it does.

It's worth to mention that Firefox doesn't show twitching problem. I can't be sure if this is caused by the CSS you have. I didn't modify your CSS.

I came across couple carousel library and did the same test to see how they handle the issue.

**Owl Carousel**

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/custom.html

Only allows dragging input. Other user inputs are disabled (scroll bar, keyboard arrow, etc). However, if you try to drag the carousel (in Chrome browser) while it's animating, you will see same jump / lag problem. Again, Firefox shows better and smoother animation with this library.

**Slick**

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

The 'autoplay' option prevents user input when carousel is animating. No scroll bar and you can only move with keyboard arrow.

**Conclusion**

As a conclusion from this long answer, few things you can do if you want to build your own carousel:

- Limit user input, only allows certain input.
- Disable scroll bar.

Or, you can use existing library out there.